# refreshing a canvas in TK containing a Matplotlib graph

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying write the code for refreshing a plot in my GUI, but every time instead of refreshing the plot in juts plots the next graph n different location.

```
 if tumortypeplot== 'Atypical Teratoid Rhabdoid Tumour':

    f = Figure(figsize=(7.5,5), dpi=100)
    f.gca().invert_xaxis()
    a = f.add_subplot(111)

    if var1.get()==1:

        a.errorbar(ppm, atrtave_pf, atrtsd_pf, linestyle='-', ecolor='g', marker='^')
        a.set_title('Atypical Teratoid - Rhabdoid Tumour_ Posterior fossa')
        a.set_xlabel('Frequency/ppm')
        a.set_ylabel('Intensity (au)')

    elif var2.get()==1:

        a.errorbar(ppm, atrtave_sp, atrtsd_sp, linestyle='-', ecolor='g', marker='^')
        a.set_title('Atypical Teratoid - Rhabdoid Tumour_ Supratentorial')
        a.set_xlabel('Frequency/ppm')
        a.set_ylabel('Intensity (au)')

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side="right")
```

I tried using a.clf() or a.clear(). But i doesn't work.
I have just started using python and appropriate your help to find out what is the problem with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `a` is an axis object, it doesn't have a clear figure `clf` method. This should raise an error, which may be hidden by a try statement? To clear the current axis, you need to call `a.cla()` (or `a.clear()`). You can then call a new plot command which should replace the axis on the current figure.

For your gui, if this doesn't work, you can clear the figure `f.clf()` and entirely replace with a new plot. Note that in `wxpython`, as part of a gui you need to use `f.clf(keep_observers=True)` and then readd subplot, etc `a=f.add_subplot(111)` to get correct result.

The fastest option, which is complicated for an errorbar, as it contains a number of objects, is to update the data in the returned handle from the errorbar function and redraw. This would look something like,

```
eb = a.errorbar(ppm, atrtave_pf, atrtsd_pf, linestyle='-', ecolor='g', marker='^')
```

Then when you've updated `ppm` and `atrtave_pf` and want to update the lines,

```
line=eb.line[0]
line.set_data(ppm, atrtave_pf)
f.canvas.draw()
```

Although you may have to update the errorbars in `eb` manually too and this may be more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comment. I tried both a.cla and  f.clf() but it still doesn't work. I am adding as:                                                                              f = Figure(figsize=(7.5,5), dpi=100)
        f.clf(keep_observers=True)
        f.gca().invert_xaxis()
        a = f.add_subplot(1,1,1)                                                                          can the issue be with  add_subplot? as every time it adds another subplot on top of the previous one.

Comment: If you use `a.gca()`, you are only clearing the axis and should **not** need to add a new subplot, instead use `a.errorbar(...)` to plot the new data on the recently cleared axis. If you clear the figure with `f.gcf()` then adding a new subplot may be necessary before calling `a.errorbar(...)`. Without a mcv example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your gui it is difficult to know how redrawing works for your case...